# Is it possible to send 2 objects of different types through parcelable?

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am trying to pass 2 objects of different type from activity1 to activity2. One of them always returns null

Heres what I have

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("type1", object1);
intent.putExtra("type2", object2);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2:

```
onCreate(Bundle bundle){
   Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
   Type1 object1 = b.getParcelable("type1");
   Type2 object2 = b.getParcelable("type2");
}
```

One of them returns null, any idea why?

I checked both objects before sending and they are in fact not null.

Comment: sorry for typo... fixed it

Comment: when you ask "is it possible", have you tried it?

Comment: You'll have to show where `object1` and `object2` are initialized.

Comment: Yes I have tried it that is why I'm getting null. One of the object is static and the other is initialized in the same method where the intent is.

Comment: Don't tell us, show us. Being static doesn't mean anything in this context.

Comment: Have you tried to send them separately? Maybe the `Parcable` implementation of one class is faulty.

Comment: are those objects implementing serializable? if yes, try intent.getSerializableExtra instead of getting from bundles

Comment: @DanielLerps I just tried to send one by one and it seems to work when I just send 1. Maybe it is faulty.